# Only show title in legend entry for raster/tile layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, print-composer, legend

When I have a legend entry for a xyz tile raster layer, such as Google satellite, in a print composer layout in QGIS, the legend includes a lot of white space underneath the title.  This would normally be where the scale is for a raster layer that's displayed as pseudo-color. Is there a way to turn this off so it doesn't affect the layout of the rest of the legend?
My current work around is to remove the legend entry and replace it with a text box, but I would prefer a solution that doesn't require the alignment and font style matching that comes with this approach.

Example layout.  In the following examples the legend includes entries for 2 vector layers and 2 raster layers.  Google Satellite is an xyz tile layer with no special styling applied.  The other raster is displayed as pseudo-color with associated styling.  Notice white space under the Google Satellite entry.
[image]

Changing the order of the legend items also leads to problems.  For example, moving the 2 vector layers up above the xyz tile entry makes the column break strange. 
[image]

This can also create problems and awkward work-arounds if your legend is laid out in a single column:

[image]

Within the "Item Properties" dialog, I can maniuplate the subgroups for other raster layers or for vector layers that have graduated or classified styling, but there is nothing to manipulate for the xyz tiles layers.  In my example legend, I could remove the entries for say 0.5 and 3.5 meters by selecting the entry and clicking remove item.  There is, however nothing in the dropdown below the xyz tiles entry:

[image]